# Database creation date in Greenplum

Tags: greenplum

Is there any way to find out Creation date of a database in Greenplum ? I tried searching but found for postgres, didn't worked in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is a Postgres-derived design, Greenplum also creates a sensible folder/file structure on the local filesystem. You can determine the  in a round-about way like this:

```
psql=# SELECT oid from pg_database where datname = 'postgres';
```

then inspect the filesystem directly:

```
$ ls -l $MASTER_DATA_DIRECTORY/base/<OID FROM QUERY ABOVE>/PG_VERSION
```

The modification date/time of that file should correspond with the database creation date/time.

For a schema, the following should work:

```
SELECT statime FROM pg_stat_last_operation p, pg_namespace n 
WHERE p.objid = n.oid AND n.nspname = '<SCHEMA NAME>' ;
```

Just for completeness, tables would look like this:

```
SELECT statime FROM pg_stat_last_operation WHERE objid = '<TABLE NAME>'::regclass
AND staactionname = 'CREATE';
```

Comment: i need to find out schema creation date also, is there any sql for that?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the process for schema creation. Can you also mark the answer as accepted?